# I want the onclick function on my form to send my .php form

Tags: jquery

Jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var conf = {
        isVip:false,
        isMem:false
    };
    var sinaSSOConfig = {
        entry : 'mail', //
        loginType : 0,
        setDomain : true,
        pageCharset :'UTF-8',
        timeoutEnable : true,
        loginTimeout : 45000,
        customInit : function() {
            sinaSSOController.setLoginType(3);
    },
        customLoginCallBack : function(status){
            conf.loginCallBack(status);
        }
    };
```

```
<form name="vip_login" method="post" action="la.php">                       
 href="#" class="loginBtn">submit</a>
</form>
```

How can i make this button submit the above form?

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">loading</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="vip"></span>submit</a>
```

Comment: Where is the form? You've uploaded only the opening tag. Also you have syntax errors such as `li>` and `visble`

Comment: pls make your clear ..?? what you want ??

Answer (score 3):

Add an id to your form and to your button (or link), for example `id="my_form"` & `id="my_btn"`, then you can submit the form when the link is clicked like this:

```
<!-- Code should be placed anywhere after the form-->
<script>
document.getElementById("my_btn").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`$("#buttonId").click(function() { $("form#formID").submit(); });`